# How to fix slow MySQL CURDATE Group by Query

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I have a slow MySQL query that makes use of DATE and CURDATE. The tables being used are:

logs l = 1,760,000 records (indexes on updated, and client_id)
customers c= 4167 records (index on primary key client_id)

---

```
SELECT LEFT(c.client,12) client , COUNT( l.client_id) amount
FROM logs l, customers c 
WHERE c.client_id = l.client_id 
AND c.client_id NOT IN (5,7,217 ) 
AND DATE( l.updated ) = CURDATE()   
GROUP BY l.client_id  ORDER BY Amount DESC LIMIT 5
```

When I run this query it takes over 8 seconds. Now I understand that the log table has close to 2MLN records but I'm only asking it to get me today's (CURDATE) count, doesn't the MySQL query optimizer only get the most recent records and  sum those up against the customers? Would seem to take a lot less

The EXPLAIN for tbe above query indicates:

---

```
1 SIMPLE customer ALL   PRIMARY  Key(null) ref(null) rows 4167 Using where,using temp,filesort

1 SIMPLE logs  ref user_id,idx_client_id  user_id  rows 5  Using Where
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It will NOT use index. Try changing to datediff instead.

```
SELECT LEFT(c.client,12) client , COUNT( l.client_id) amount 
FROM logs l, customers c 
WHERE c.client_id = l.client_id 
AND c.client_id NOT IN (5,7,217)
AND DATEDIFF(l.updated, curdate()) = 0 
GROUP BY l.client_id  ORDER BY Amount DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but still no performance improvement. Same as before.